# How to validate if studentNo is a 11-digit no

Tags: java

Good day!

I have a class Student with  attribute String studentNo

Using OO, how can I validate if the input is an 11-digit no.

I can do this:

```
If(studentNo.length()<11){

}
```

to validate.. but how can I determine if it is a number or not.

And what are the other methods on how can I do this validation.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Most languages will have different approach to do the same thing and some may have in-built facilities as well. Which one are you using?

Comment: @check123 Well, the question is tagged with Java, so that'd be a good bet right there.

Comment: Anyone suggesting a regular expression to this have not recognized that this is a student, who will then have _two_ problems.

Comment: @Thorbjorn. Apparently LP is after regex after all. But I voted for your post 'cause it makes sense. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would want to use a regular expression, like this:

```
^[0-9]{11}$
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check the following:

- The length of the string is 11.
- Each of the 11 character is a zero, a one, a two, a three, a four, a five, a six, a seven, an eight or a nine.

For a complex check you frequently store the result in a boolean.  First setting it to true and if any of the conditions fail you set it to false.  You then know in the end if all conditions held, by seing that it is still true.

Comment: I would change the check so that is checks that the digit is larger or equal to '0' and less or equal to '9'. Another option would be to use Character.isDigit for all characters (if you accept that you then also will accept e.g. arabic digits)

Comment: @Kaj, checking for a range assumes you are familiar with the unicode character map.  I believe the OP to be too early in the learning process to be familiar with that.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool isNum = true;
try {
    Integer.parseInt(studentNo);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e {
    // if we hit here it is not a number...
    isNum = false;
}
```

Comment: Is this a good practice? I thought Exceptiones should not be used for this purpose?

Comment: Does Java have a similar concept to .NET's `TryParse`? That'd eliminate the try/catch.

Comment: @Sarah: It'd be nice to avoid it, but the simplest way to determine if a string is an integer is to ask the JVM. It's not ideal, but it's simple enough to understand and not really *that* bad.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: presumably you would still do the length check first, then do this check for numericalness(?).

Comment: @Matthew, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932761/how-to-validate-if-studentno-is-a-11-digit-no/5932799#5932799

Comment: In general using Exceptions for code flow is not a good thing to do, however in simple cases like this, as long as it is obvious what the code is doing, it is ok imho - @Matthew, tryParse would be ideal ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use regex:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

For example, in java you would do this:

studentNo.matches("[0-9]{11}");

Answer (score 0):

Semantically, you could use

```
try {
    new BigInteger(studentNo);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    ...
}
```

However, the regexp solutions might be more elegant with respect to the "don't use exceptions as a form of input checking" paradigm (exception handling is generally more expensive than simple checks). So, it depends on whether you want the code to be semantically clear or whether you want it to be efficient.