# how to store "12000000000" or a 11 digit number in java

Tags: java

Which data type should be used to store such a big number like in an example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932761/how-to-validate-if-studentno-is-a-11-digit-no) question?

Comment: Does it really make sense as a number? Or is it more of a String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably what you're looking for is:

- `BigDecimal` if you want decimals
- `BigInteger` otherwise

Source: [java.math
Class BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html).